# Reducing Vertical Margin List of Equations

Tags: spacing, tocloft

I am trying to add a List of Equations to my dissertation that matches the style of the list of tables and list of figures.  I am very close but am hung up on the last step.  How can I reduce the vertical space between the "EQUATION .. PAGE" line and the line that shows the first equation?

[image]

I am using the tocloft package and the code to generate this table is shown below

```
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{LIST OF EQUATIONS \vskip 0.0in \noindent     \textnormal{EQUATION} \hfill \textnormal{PAGE}}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}% Width of equation number in List of Equations
\setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{2em}
```

I think I am looking for another `\setlength` command but have scoured the `tocloft` documentation and cant seem to find what parameter to set.

Comment: in some circumstances, the "`\listof...`" inserts extra space between entries for separate chapters.  in situations i'm familiar with, this takes the form of `\addvspace {10\p@ }` in the `.lo*` file.  while this shouldn't accumulate, there may be something else in that file that suppresses the `add` check.  compare your new `.lo*` file to the comparable `.lof' to see what might be different.  it also looks like you might be using `\doublespacing`; you should probably turn that off until after all the lists are output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `\cftafterequtitle` to place your `EQUATION`...`PAGE` headings, and set an appropriate length `\cftafterequtitleskip` to establish the distance between the entire heading and your first entry (see section **2.2 Changing the titles** in the [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}% Width of equation number in List of Equations
\setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{2em}
\renewcommand{\cftafterequtitle}{\par\noindent \textnormal{EQUATION} \hfill \textnormal{PAGE}}
\setlength{\cftafterequtitleskip}{0pt}% Space between \cftafterequtitle and first list entry

% Just for this example, redefine \listofmyequations to keep the list entries for re-use.
\let\oldlistofmyequations\listofmyequations
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\listofmyequations}{{%
  \@fileswfalse\oldlistofmyequations}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{multido}% Just for this example

\begin{document}
\listofmyequations
\begin{equation} A\myequations{test1} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} B\myequations{test2} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} C\myequations{test3} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} D\myequations{test4} \end{equation}

\multido{\i=1+1}{10}{% Print 10 \listofmyequations, each with different \cftafterequtitleskip
  \clearpage
  \setlength{\cftafterequtitleskip}{\i\baselineskip}
  \listofmyequations
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: fantasic.  Thank you for your help.  Would you mind looking at this question as well?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191848/centering-list-of-x-and-following-with-text