# Centering List of X and Following with Text

Tags: spacing, tocloft

With the tocloft package, I can add text under the title of a "List of Z" at the beginning of a latex document:

```
\renewcommand{\cftafterZtitle}{\par\noindent \textnormal{Z} \hfill \textnormal{PAGE}}
```

Using the following I can center the title "List of Z":

```
\renewcommand{\cftZtitlefont}{\hfill\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterZtitle}{\hfill}
```

But when I try to combine the two commands, it moves the text to the right margin instead of the center:

```
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill\par\noindent \textnormal{Z} \hfill \textnormal{PAGE}}
```

Does anyone know how to both center the title "List of Z" and have text below the title?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Don't know the package but usually centring is done with things like `\centering` or `\begin{center}` rather than `\hfill` which does not usually make a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an empty `\hbox` after the second `\hfill` (See [**egreg**'s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24921/3954) to [What is \null and when do we need to use it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24919/3954)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill\null\par\noindent\textnormal{Z}\hfill \textnormal{PAGE}}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\noindent X\hrulefill Y% for coparison only

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use `\hfil` instead:

```
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfil\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfil\par\textnormal{Z}\hfill \textnormal{PAGE}}
```